# Pause delay on hover of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have the following jQuery that shows a div and then hides it after a delay

```
$('.myDiv').slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow');
```

This is working as expected, however, is there any way that if `myDiv` is hovered before it slides back away, that it can pause the delay?

Answer (score 1):

Use `stop()` method.The stop() method stops the currently running animation for the selected elements.

```
$('.myDiv').on('hover',function(){
$(this).stop();
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({height: 300}, 3000);
    });
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $("div").stop();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<button id="start">Start Animation</button>
</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this seems to work... The div is showed by a different script calling `$('.myDiv').slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow');` and the .stop function doesn't seem to do anything. However using `$(".myDiv").hover(function(){ $(".myDiv").stop(); });` does seem to stop it, although it seems to stop halfway, which I want to ignore if it's already started to slide up, and also once you hover out, it's then frozen forever and doesn't continue to slide.

Comment: That seems completely irrelevant to what I'm trying to do